# URL rewriting for Alias in webserver

Tags: webserver, websphere, url-rewrite-module, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have two copy of our XYZ Application ( Test, Training). They are two different applications in websphere having two different datatbases. We usually tend to have one webserver per websphere application. Although I know we can have multiple webservers. In my webserver we have created a variable called LoginExternal as shown below which points to a physical folder with the same name in the application server.
Alias /**LoginExternal** //winxen90/LoginExternal$

We refer to the LoginExternal variable through our HTML as shown below.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/**LoginExternal**/Data/LoginAnnouncements.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/**LoginExternal**/Data/LoginForms.js"></script>
```

href="JavaScript:LGNEXTUTILS_OpendExternalPage( '/**LoginExternal**/Pages/LoginAnnouncements.html' );">

The problem we are facing is that with this setup the two applications are forced to use data from one physical folder called LoginExternal because of the webserver alias. I am looking for a solution by which even if we have two physical folders LoginExternal1 , LoginExternal2 one for each application The HTML files from each application should refer to the correct LoginExternal folder. I am  hoping we can achieve this by some form of URL rewriting.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you want the HTML source to just use a single path, but have that go do different directories depending on which web application it's being requested from?

Comment: If this had been JSP file you could have used request.getContextPath() to replace /**LoginExternal**. Since the files are HTML and you are using JavaScript to load the html, cannot you use relative path syntax like ../ so that the URL gets automatically mapped to base URL?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say that this might not be possible without using separate virtual hosts, but...

I think your Rewrite condition can compare the Referrer header against your two web applications' context roots.